# How to find the Transport Request with my custom objects?

Tags: abap, transport, sap-basis, function-module

I've copied two Function Modules `QM06_SEND_PAPER_STEP2` and `QM06_FM_TASK_CLAIM_SEND_PAPER` to similar Z* Function Modules. I've put these FMs into a `ZQM06` Function Group which was created by another developer.

I want to use Transaction `SCC1` to move my developments from one client to another. In transaction `SE01` Transport Organizer I don't find the names of my 2 function modules anywhere.

How can I find out the change request with my work?

I copied the FM in order to modify functionality and I know FMs are client independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function modules, like other ABAP workbench entities, are client-independent. That is, you do not need to copy them between clients on the same instance.

However, you can find the transport request that contains your changes by going to transaction SE37, entering the name of your function module, and then choosing `Utilities -> Versions -> Version Management` from the menu.

Provided you did not put the changes into a local package (like `$TMP`) the system will have asked you for a transport request when you saved or activated your changes, that is, unless the function group is in a modifiable transport request, in which case it would have created a new task for your user under that request which will contain you changes. To check the package, use `Goto -> Object Directory Entry` from the menu in SE37.

Answer (score 1):

Function modules are often added to transports under the function group name, especially if they're new.

The easiest way to fin dhte transport is to go to SE37, display the function module, and then go to Version Management.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from mydoghasworms is correct. Alternatively you can also use transaction SE03 -> Search for Objects in Requests/Tasks  (top of the transaction screen) -> check the box next to "R3TR FUGR" and type in your function group name.